# How to do a dynamic join in a JSON object in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a nested json string that I'm parsing using the parse_json() function. Sample data looks like

{
"one":"OneValue",
"four""FourValue",
{"1":"stringA", "24":"stringBlah"..}}

The values "1" and "24" in the nested json string are keys to a mapping table.

Sample mapping table data
"1": "One"
"24": "TwentyFour"

I'd like to join the keys in the nested json with the mapping table and have a query that outputs the values instead of the keys. Any suggestions on how I can do this dynamic join on the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not entirely sure i got your intention correctly, but the following may give you a direction:

```
let T1 = datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({ "one":"OneValue", "four": "FourValue", "prop":{"1":"stringA", "24":"stringBlah"}}),
    dynamic({ "one":"OneValue", "four": "FourValue", "prop":{"3":"stringB", "24":"stringBlahBlah"}})
]
;
let T2 = datatable(i:int, s:string)
[
    1,  "One",
    24, "TwentyFour",
    3,  "Three"
]
;
let map = toscalar(
    T2
    | summarize make_bag(pack(tostring(i), s))
)
;
T1
| project prop = d.prop
| mv-apply prop on 
(
    extend key = tostring(bag_keys(prop)[0])
    | project p = pack(tostring(map[key]), prop[tostring(key)])
    | summarize result = make_bag(p)
)
```

this returns:

```
|result                                              |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|{"One":   "stringA", "TwentyFour": "stringBlah"}    |
|{"Three": "stringB", "TwentyFour": "stringBlahBlah"}|
```